# Android Studio Changed my Modules, and now my Unit Tests are Red all over

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, junit

I recently upgraded my Android Studio to Hedgehog, and since then, any time I try to edit a unit test, it complains that classes I define within the same module are not able to be found, and it insists that I need to add a dependency to the same module. I see now that it has changed all my modules and split them all into 3 submodules, which is messing me up big time.

ex. if I have a module named "Bunny" the module would then be split into Bunny.main, Bunny.unitTest, and Bunny.androidTest.

The stupid part is, whether I run the unit tests in AS or using the gradle cmd, the tests run fine and pass without complaints. It's just the IDE that complains it can't find the classes. Is there some setting or configuration I missed somewhere to prevent AS from splitting my modules like this?